# I lost my Photoshop CS6 default brushes, can I download them?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

So it seems like I have accidentally deleted my default brushes some time ago (from the disk), and I would like to get them back. I searched online but didn't find them. It'd be helpful if someone could give me a link to download them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might need to reinstall Photoshop on your computer.

Comment: For CS6, they would be on the installation disk.

Answer (score 1):

In the Brushes pallete (Window->Brush Presets), click on the top-right menu. It’s a little downward pointing black triangle with 3 lines next to it. It’s very small and not obvious that it’s a menu.

[image]

Then in the menu that appears, choose “Reset Brushes…”
[image]

If that doesn’t work, then your default brushes really ARE gone and you will have to reinstall Photoshop.